# Css and Javascript best way to make loading state, in animations and out animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I want to make an introductory DOM animation when the page loads, and if I click a link the page make an out animation and a loading state, and when the page is loaded make the in animation. What the best way to achieve this? Any suggestions, links tutorial, videos are more than welcome. Thanks a lot guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

A good way to create animations efficiently is to use [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

You can create all kinds of animations that are triggered when the object is loaded.

Then using javascript you can add or remove additional css classes to trigger additional animations.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.Bx').toggleClass('Grow');
});
```

```css
.Bx {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease;  
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Triggered animation */
.Grow {
  background-color: #45CEE0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Bx"></div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me"></input>
```